# How to dynamically select columns and update them based on variable value?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which stores the total income on monthly basis. The columns are named as column_1, column_2, ... , column_12. Each month I need to update the value on the column corresponding to the month. For example, Jan = column_1, Feb = column_2 etc. How to dynamically select the column and update the required column every month in a single update statement instead of writing multiple if else in PLSQL? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) is appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Quite painfully.  You should probably fix your data model, so each month's data is stored *in a row* not in a column.

But if you are stuck with someone else's bad data model, you can use:

```
update t
    set month_1 = (case when extract(month from sysdate) = 1 then :val else month_1 end),
        month_1 = (case when extract(month from sysdate) = 2 then :val else month_2 end),
        . . .   -- repeat for all months
    where <whatever other conditions you have>;
```

In other words, you are updating all columns.  However, 11 of them will get the value they already have.

Comment: This looks fair enough. No other option, I am stuck with an existing model and cannot make changes to the structure now. Thanks a lot!